# Image uploads with Pyramid and SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, deform

How one should do image file uploads with Pyramid, SQLAlchemy and deform? Preferably so that one can easily get image thumbnail tags in the templates. What configuration is needed (store images on the file system backend, so on).

Comment: Depot is framework agnostic upload framework with support to SQLAlchemy and Amazon S3 depot.readthedocs.org/en/latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is by no means specifically asking one thing. Here however is a view which defines a form upload with deform, tests the input for a valid image file, saves a record to a database, and then even uploads it to amazon S3. This example is shown under the links to the various documentation I have referenced.
To upload a file with deform [see the documentation.](http://deform2demo.repoze.org/file/)

If you want to learn how to save image files to disk, see this article [see the official documentation](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html)

Then if you want to learn how to save new items with SQLAlchemy [see the SQLAlchemy tutorial.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)

If you want to ask a better question where a more precise detailed answer can be given for each section, then please do so.

```python
@view_config(route_name='add_portfolio_item', 
renderer='templates/user_settings/deform.jinja2',
permission='view')
def add_portfolio_item(request):

    user = request.user
    # define store for uploaded files
    class Store(dict):
        def preview_url(self, name):
            return ""

    store = Store()
    # create a form schema
    class PortfolioSchema(colander.MappingSchema):
        description = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
            validator = Length(max=300),
            widget = text_area,
            title = "Description, tell us a few short words desribing your picture")
        upload = colander.SchemaNode(
                deform.FileData(),
                widget=widget.FileUploadWidget(store))

    schema = PortfolioSchema()
    myform = Form(schema, buttons=('submit',), action=request.url)

    # if form has been submitted
    if 'submit' in request.POST:

        controls = request.POST.items()
        try:
            appstruct = myform.validate(controls)
        except ValidationFailure, e:
            return {'form':e.render(), 'values': False}
        # Data is valid as far as colander goes

        f = appstruct['upload']
        upload_filename = f['filename']
        extension = os.path.splitext(upload_filename)[1]
        image_file = f['fp']

        # Now we test for a valid image upload
        image_test = imghdr.what(image_file)
        if image_test == None:
            error_message = "I'm sorry, the image file seems to be invalid is invalid"
            return {'form':myform.render(), 'values': False, 'error_message':error_message,
            'user':user}


        # generate date and random timestamp
        pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        random_n = str(time.time())

        filename = random_n + '-' + user.user_name + extension
        upload_dir = tmp_dir
        output_file = open(os.path.join(upload_dir, filename), 'wb')

        image_file.seek(0)
        while 1:
            data = image_file.read(2<<16)
            if not data:
                break
            output_file.write(data)
        output_file.close()

        # we need to create a thumbnail for the users profile pic
        basewidth = 530
        max_height = 200
        # open the image we just saved
        root_location = open(os.path.join(upload_dir, filename), 'r')
        image = pilImage.open(root_location)
        if image.size[0] > basewidth:
            # if image width greater than 670px
            # we need to recduce its size
            wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
            hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
            portfolio_pic = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), pilImage.ANTIALIAS)
        else:
            # else the image can stay the same size as it is
            # assign portfolio_pic var to the image
            portfolio_pic = image

        portfolio_pics_dir = os.path.join(upload_dir, 'work')

        quality_val = 90
        output_file = open(os.path.join(portfolio_pics_dir, filename), 'wb')
        portfolio_pic.save(output_file, quality=quality_val)

        profile_full_loc = portfolio_pics_dir + '/' + filename

        # S3 stuff
        new_key = user.user_name + '/portfolio_pics/' + filename
        key = bucket.new_key(new_key)
        key.set_contents_from_filename(profile_full_loc)
        key.set_acl('public-read')

        public_url = key.generate_url(0, query_auth=False, force_http=True)

        output_dir = os.path.join(upload_dir)
        output_file = output_dir + '/' + filename
        os.remove(output_file)
        os.remove(profile_full_loc)

        new_image = Image(s3_key=new_key, public_url=public_url,
         pub_date=pub_date, bucket=bucket_name, uid=user.id,
         description=appstruct['description'])
        DBSession.add(new_image)
        # add the new entry to the association table.
        user.portfolio.append(new_image)

        return HTTPFound(location = route_url('list_portfolio', request))

    return dict(user=user, form=myform.render())
```

Comment: Thanks! This is freaking awesome answer. It connects all the dots a person without relevant experience of integrating the subsystems in question cannot know.

Comment: Luckily I comment all my code like this, so this is a working view taken from an old project :-)

Comment: I suspect SQLAlchemy doesn't have anything (semi)native for image fields like Django's ImageField? It could store the filename in the field, filename id, etc.

Comment: No, thats because the Django base and ORM are so intertwined and only designed for use with each other. SQLAlchemy is designed for use with any framework, but again this is like 2 lines of code to add into your project.